# Best way to link data and ComboBox items

Tags: java, swing, data-structures, jcombobox

I am having difficulty making a JComboBox that will be used to filter and to select a particular custom data object that is drawn from internal data-structure and the value shown in JComboBox would be just a value of a one field in that custom data object, or even a field of field (that is a custom object itself) of the enclosing custom data object. For example, I have device model registration form.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q-_ii_V7SWDBFvUJGw0cd2BEWP3BnM0H

Model has a Name, a Specification, a Device Type and a Manufacturer that define it. This is the actual Model class that I use:

```
public class Models
{
    private DeviceTypes deviceType;
    private Manufacturers manufacturer;
    private String name;

    //getters and setters
}
```

This is further part of a HashMap that contains all Models with their ID.

```
public Map<Integer,Models> modelsTable = new HashMap<Integer, Models>();
```

I want to be able to add and remove items from JComboBox and to select actual data repersesnted with JComboBox items to create new models with those objects.
What is the standard way to do this? I have created a ComboBox renderer:

```
public class DeviceTypeRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3442865560696889757L;

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        if (value instanceof DeviceTypes)
        {
            value = ((DeviceTypes)value).getName();
        }

        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        return this;
    }
}

public class ManufacturersRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3723328665061573656L;

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        if (value instanceof Manufacturers)
        {
            value = ((Manufacturers)value).getName();
        }

        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        return this;
    }
}
```

And then I just add or remove them as data objects.

```
DeviceTypes deviceType = new DeviceTypes(name,description);

comboBoxDeviceType.addItem(deviceType);
```

And JComboBox displayes `deviceType.getName();`

What would be the best way to do the reverse. To get a actual data class form JComboBox item selection? I probably did all this the wrong way and am using lot of bad practice. If you see that please inform me to correct myself, and I would appreciate it if you could show me how to implement this correctly. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found better and more elegant overall solution for this problem by using ComboBox models.

First of all the data objects are stored in a HashMap with String keys, that are uniqe, and represent actual names od each data object.

```
private HashMap<String, DataElement> uniqueStringMap = new HashMap<String, DataElement>();
```

Second ComboBox model is created form those keys by taking the key set of the HashMap.

```
public static DefaultComboBoxModel<String> getModel(DataType dataType)
{
    String[] items = (String[]) DataManager.getDataTable(dataType)
                                           .getUniqueStringMap()
                                           .keySet().toArray();

    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(items);
    return model;
}
```

And then in the GUI controller the ComboBox model is set.

```
deviceGUI.getDeviceRegistrationPanel().setDeviceTypeCmbModel(CmbModelFactory.getModel(DataType.DEVICE_TYPE));
```

And in the actual Swing class the JComboBox does not know about the actual data objects from the Model, and it has simple design.

```
private JComboBox<String> cmbDeviceType = new JComboBox<String>();
```

It's model is set form the controller with a method.

```
public void setDeviceTypeCmbModel(ComboBoxModel<String> model)
{
    cmbDeviceType.setModel(model);
}
```

The data retrival is done by geting the selected item in the ComboBox.

```
public String getDeviceType()
{
    return (String) cmbDeviceType.getSelectedItem();
}
```

And then that String value is used to get the actual data object.

```
public static DeviceType getDeviceType(String name)
{
    return (DeviceType) DataManager.getByUniqueString(DataType.DEVICE_TYPE, name);
}
```

I hope this helps someone.